# Random number Array sorted out

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

For school I making a project for java, right now I got a problem.

I have to sort it out into a column 10 on the X 10000(rows) on the Y
Next to that I have to sort this out..

I hope someone can help me with my problem, I searched everywhere, but I can't find how to do both.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

public class MijnLoop7 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] integers = new int[10];
        int min = 0;
        int max = 100000;
        int aantal = 100000;
        int random = (int) (Math.random()*((aantal-min)+1))+min;
        
        for(int x=0; x<max; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<10; y++)
                integers[y] = rand.nextInt(100000);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `jav.util.Arrays.sort` perhaps. Also, you're printing `integers` every single time you add a new number to your array (a million times, I think) - you probably want to move that print statement out of your loops.

Comment: *I have to sort it out into a collum 10 on the X 10000(rows) on the Y Next to that i have to sort this out..* ... I'm having a hard time to understand what you try to accomplish. Can you rephrase that description to make it clearer? Usually it's very helpful to have a (small) example together with your description; in particular of the output you expect your program to produce.

Comment: try to use english when coding, would make it easier for others to understand your code.Your Random rand = new Random() is designed as an alternative of Math.random(), so why not using your variable rand instead? Would it be correct to assume that you're building a 3-dimensional sorted array? Please elaborate